# Append HTML from an XHR request using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript

If I had HTML content like this:

```
<div id="my1">
    <div id="1">This is div 1</div> 
    <div id="2">This is div 2</div> 
    <div id="3">This is div 3</div> 
    <div id="4">This is div 4</div> 
    <div id="5">This is div 5</div> 
</div>
```

How can I append an HTML string returned from an XHR request that comes in like this:

```
<div class="cA cB cC" data-type"a">
    <div>Success Message Here<div>
    <div class="cL">Undo</div>
</div>
```

So the end result is:

```
<div id="my1">
    <div id="1">This is div 1</div> 
    <div id="2">This is div 2</div> 
    <div id="3">This is div 3</div> 
    <div id="4">This is div 4</div> 
    <div id="5">This is div 5</div>
    <div class="cA cB cC" data-type"a">
       <div>Success Message Here<div>
       <div class="cL">Undo</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The thing is, I don't want to do `document.createElement(div).appendChild()` since it already comes formatted with classes and data attributes.

Is there a way to simply add this HTML to where I need it?

Answer (score 0):

You can append to the div's innerHTML. Assuming your content to add is stored in a variable called `html`:

`document.getElementById('my1').innerHTML += html`

Comment: You will replace all elements and can lose cursor position if you have an input inside the element

Comment: @MarkPartola oh good point I never realized there was a function which took care of that

Comment: @Norman I suggest looking at MarkPartola's answer instead for a safer/better approach

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to make sure that data is safe to insert it directly to prevent XSS.
Then you can use method called insertAdjacentHTML:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML
You can choose place to insert your raw HTML

```
element.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', rawHtml)
```